# Save array of images to user in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to save array of images to the user?

I already created a form and I'm at the saving part.

I already have this code:

```
update_user_meta($user->ID, 'gallery', $_POST['gallery_images']);
```

`gallery_images` contains the array of input images in the form.

And I know this is not working. Is it possible to save an array of images in user? If possible, how?

PS.
I'm using the latest version of wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Revised answer)*

As pointed in the comment to the other answer, you can use [`media_handle_upload()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_upload/) to upload the images, but since the function only supports *single* upload, then for *multiple* uploads, you can set a temporary `$_FILES` item like so:

```php
// Load upload-related and other required functions.
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php';
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php';
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php';

$post_id = 0;   // set to the proper post ID, if attaching to a post
$uploaded = []; // attachment IDs

foreach ( $_FILES['gallery_images']['tmp_name'] as $key => $file ) {
    // Set a temporary $_FILES item.
    $_FILES['_tmp_gallery_image'] = [
        'name'     => $_FILES['gallery_images']['name'][ $key ],
        'type'     => $_FILES['gallery_images']['type'][ $key ],
        'size'     => $_FILES['gallery_images']['size'][ $key ],
        'tmp_name' => $file,
        'error'    => $_FILES['gallery_images']['error'][ $key ],
    ];

    // Upload the file/image.
    $att_id = media_handle_upload( '_tmp_gallery_image', $post_id );

    if ( ! is_wp_error( $att_id ) ) {
        $uploaded[] = $att_id;
    }
}
unset( $_FILES['_tmp_gallery_image'] );

// Save the attachment IDs.
$user = wp_get_current_user();
update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'gallery', $uploaded );
```

And I'm saving the attachment IDs, but of course, it's up to you if you'd rather save the image URLs, etc.

PS: You can check the original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55827900/revisions) to see how you can also upload the images using [`media_handle_sideload()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_sideload/). (It works well, but instead of going through a wrapper (function), we should just call `media_handle_upload()` unless if you're "uploading" external/remote image/file.) Sorry about that answer.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can **serialize** the data, and when you need it **unserialize** it.

```
update_user_meta($user->ID, 'gallery', serialize($_POST['gallery_images']));
```

**serialize:**
https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.serialize.php

Comment: So if I do that, the images are automatically uploaded? I don't need to upload the image manually?

Comment: I don't get what you mean. What is inside `$_POST['gallery_images']` ?

Comment: As I said, that is an array of file images in the form I put it like this: `<input type="file" name="gallery_images[]" accept="image/*" />`. This code can have one or more occurences.

Comment: Oh so you need to check the documentation for the media uploads first: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload . Retrieve all attachment ids with this function and serialize them as i showed you.

Comment: Maybe you can also take a look at advanced custom fields, a wordpress plugin to add custom fields as it said.